# Сортировка словаря Python

Tags: python, сортировка

Добрый день.
Есть словарь следующего содержания:

```
{"среда": "физика", "четверг": "русский", "понедельник": "схемотехника", "пятница": "выходной", "вторник": "география"}
```

И есть список такого содержания:

```
["понедельник", "вторник", "среда", "четверг", "пятница"]
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как отсортировать словарь по списку? Ну или вообще привести его в нормальный вид (чтобы дни недели шли по порядку)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Словарь в питоне не сохраняет порядок элементов.

Вы можете использовать особый упорядоченный тип словаря - OrderedDict.

Например, вот так вы можете из вашего словаря и списка получить правильно упорядоченный OrderedDict:

```
from collections import OrderedDict


source_dict = {
    "среда": "физика",
    "четверг": "русский",
    "понедельник": "схемотехника",
    "пятница": "выходной",
    "вторник": "география"
}

week = ["понедельник", "вторник", "среда", "четверг", "пятница"]

result = OrderedDict()

for day in week:
    result[day] = source_dict[day]

print(result)

# Вы получите: OrderedDict([('понедельник', 'схемотехника'), ('вторник', 'география'), ('среда', 'физика'), ('четверг', 'русский'), ('пятница', 'выходной')])
```

Ну, или можно записать чуть-чуть лаконичнее, если вы знакомы с генераторными выражениями:

```
from collections import OrderedDict


source_dict = {
    "среда": "физика",
    "четверг": "русский",
    "понедельник": "схемотехника",
    "пятница": "выходной",
    "вторник": "география"
}

week = ["понедельник", "вторник", "среда", "четверг", "пятница"]

result = OrderedDict((day, source_dict[day]) for day in week)

print(result)

# Результат тот же самый
```

UPD: Немножко поправил в соответствии с комментариями от Timofey Bondarev - за что ему спасибо.

Comment: Что-то я долго оформлял своё решение. В вашем можно упростить добавление элемента в словарь: вместо использования `update` можно использовать присваивание по индексу `result[day] = source_dict[day]`

Comment: Спасибо большое, вы очень помогли

Comment: @TimofeyBondarev, да хорошее замечание. Так действительно более ясно получается.

Comment: И в генераторе списков не обязательно создавать список, можно использовать генераторное выражение: `OrderedDict((day, source_dict[day]) for day in week)`

Comment: или самую суть: `OrderedDict(zip(week, itemgetter(*week)(source_dict)))`  или `OrderedDict(zip(week, map(source_dict.get, week)))`. Оба менее читаемы (в обычном коде, я бы предпочёл версию с генератором, предложенную @TimofeyBondarev)